# Filter out recurring error in Chrome JS console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I constantly see recurring Mixpanel-related errors in Chrome's JS console, and I would like to filter them out. All of the errors contain `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mixpanel.com`. What's the best way to go about filtering these errors out while **still keeping other errors visible**?

Note: I'm running Chrome's latest stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the filter icon, tick Regex and write a filter that looks like

```
^\s*(!?XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api\.mixpanel\.com)
```

---

But really you should consider fixing the error rather than hiding it

Comment: It's a Mixpanel thing. They don't send down a response to tracking events I send them while developing locally. Not a big deal, and it's just polluting my console, making it difficult to noticed relevant errors.

Comment: Actually turns out this is not working. It seems to be filtering out the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need this, but you can achieve this by overriding `window.onerror` method:

```
var oldOnError = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function( errorMsg, url, lineNumber ) {
    if( errorMsg.indexOf( 'XMLHttpRequest' ) === -1 && oldOnError ) {
        return oldOnError(errorMsg, url, lineNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call `oldOnError` as `oldOnError.apply(this, arguments)`